# Spring Batch (Boot) - Using custom app data directory for application configuration - App uses previous run data and not current

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot / Batch app. I want to use an "app data directory" (not the same as a properties file) versus a db based datastore (ie: SQL/Mongo).

The data stored in the app data directory is aggregated from several webservices and stored as XML. Each Step within the Job will fetch data and write locally, then the next Step in the chain will pick up the created Files and process for the next step (and so on).

The problem here, is each Step will only fetch previous app run data. For example, the data at app start time and not directly after the Step execution.

I understand what is happening here, that Spring is checking for any resources at launch and using them as-is before the Step actually is run.

Is there a magic trick to requesting Spring to stop loading specified resources/Files at app launch?

Note: Using Java Config, not XML and the latest Spring/Boot/Batch versions, also tried @StepScope for all reader/writers

Repo: https://github.com/RJPalombo/salesforceobjectreplicator

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, add your configuration classes.  It could help to understand what you are up for. What kind of job parameter do you pass when launching your job?

Comment: I just added the repo to Github. Link is in post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no magic :-)

Firstly, your code is very well structured and easy to understand.

The first thing, that pops in my eyes is: Why aren't you using the standard readers and writers from springbatch (FlatFileItemReader/Writer, StaxReader/Writer). There is no need to implement this logic by yourself.

As far as I see, the problem is that you load the whole data in the constructor of the readers.

The whole job-structure (together with step, reader, writer, and processor instances) is created when the spring context is loaded, way before the job actually is executed.

Therefore, the reader just read empty files.

The simplest fix you could make is to implement the "ItemStream" interface for all your readers and writers.

And then reading the data in the open method, instead of the constructur. The open method is called, just before the steps get executed.

But that is only a quick fix and only helps to understand the behaviour of springbatch. The problem with this approach is, that all data is loaded at once, which means, that the memory usage will increase with the amount of data; hence, the memory would blow up when reading lots of data. Something we don't want to have when doing batch processing.

So, I'll recommend that you have a look at the standard readers and writers. Have a look how they work, debug into them. See when the open/close methods are called; check what happens when the read method is called and what it does.
It is not that complicated and having a look at your code, I'm sure that you are able to understand this very fast.